# What does the error `remote: fatal: bad object 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000` mean?

Tags: git

After pushing to a git repo, I got this error:

```
[trusktr@starlancer bml]$ git push origin trusktr
Password: 
Counting objects: 13, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (7/7), done.
Writing objects: 100% (7/7), 763 bytes, done.
Total 7 (delta 6), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: fatal: bad object 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
To ssh://trusktr@buzztard.git.sourceforge.net/gitroot/buzztard/bml
 * [new branch]      trusktr -> trusktr
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Anything that starts with `remote:` is something printed by the host receiving the upload.  In this case, it almost certainly is a (slightly) broken post-receive hook that does not handle "new branch created" properly.  (A new branch has, as its "old" sha1, the NULL sha1 0{40}.  If the hook tries to use that as a commit-ID, it fails because no commit should ever have that ID.)